# Shopify - how can I display the "Browse by subcategories" form on index.liquid?

Tags: php, html, css, shopify

What I'm trying to do, is to create a shortcut on the index page for the subcategories from the catalog page.
On the catalog page, I have this code for browsing through the collection:

```
<form action="" class="navigation">
    <div class="category-selector-wrapper">
        <label>Browse by collection:</label>
        <div class="category">
            <select class="navigationSelector">
                <option value="/collections/all">All</option>
                {% for col in collections %}
                    <option value="{{ col.url }}"{% if collection.handle == col.handle %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ col.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% assign colItems = collection.all_tags | size %}
    {% if colItems > 0 %}
    <div class="category-selector-wrapper">
        <label>Subcategory:</label>
        <div class="category">
            <select class="navigationSelector">
                {% if collection.handle %}
                    <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">All</option>
                {% elsif collection.products.first.type == collection.title %}
                    <option value="{{ collection.title | url_for_type }}">All</option>
                {% elsif collection.products.first.vendor == collection.title %}
                    <option value="{{ collection.title | url_for_vendor }}">All</option>
                {% endif %}

                {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
                    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                        <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/{{ tag | handleize }}" selected="selected">{{ tag }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                        <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <label class="total">{{ collection.products_count }} {{ collection.products_count | pluralize: 'item', 'items' }} total</label>
</form>
```

What I've tried, is input this code below in the index.liquid:

```
  <form action="" class="navigation">
    <div class="category-selector-wrapper">
            <label>Subcategory:</label>
            <div class="category">
                <select class="navigationSelector">
                    {% if collection.handle %}
                        <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">All</option>
                    {% elsif collection.products.first.type == collection.title %}
                        <option value="{{ collection.title | url_for_type }}">All</option>
                    {% elsif collection.products.first.vendor == collection.title %}
                        <option value="{{ collection.title | url_for_vendor }}">All</option>
                    {% endif %}


                            <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/{{ tag | handleize }}" selected="selected">{{ tag }}</option>

                            <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag }}</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

What this code does, is display the shortcut, but I can only select "All". The drop-down doesn't display any other subcategories. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the index page the `collection` variable is not set. You need to assign it yourself using something along the lines of:

```
{% assign collection = collections.all %}
```

(above the code you already have)

`collections.all` is an [Automatic Collection](http://wiki.shopify.com/Collections#Automatic_collections).

Comment: Still, I only get the "All" option for subcategories.